# How to use clickonce to deploy a desktop application with a URL

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am developing a desktop application. I need a URL which is linked to a button in a web application. On that action, my desktop application runs and action is performed.
I am having error generating a URL for the desktop application.

Comment: Perhaps flesh this out with an example.  Do you have some code?

Comment: I am making a .net core web application to conduct election on the basis of biometric. now the biometric machcine digital persona 4000b cannot be integrated with the web app. Now I have made a desktop app to enroll fingerprints. I want that the web app call the desktop app by a url and give the id as a argument to the desktop app to enroll fingerprint for that argument id. In return fingerprint is returned that is stored in DB.